# Why can't a parent pointer be assigned to a child pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a trivial inheritance case following:

```
class Person {
public:
    const char* name;
public:
    Person()
        : name("Unknown person") {}
    
    Person(const char* name)
        : name(name) {}
};

class Student : public Person {
public:
    Student()
        : Person("Unknown Student") {}
};
```

If I assign a child pointer to a parent pointer, it is totally legal:

```
Student *s = new Student();
Person *p = s;
```

But if I do the other way, assigning a parent pointer to a child pointer, it would cause an error:

```
Person *p = new Person();
Student *s = p;
```

The error is: invalid conversion from ‘Person*’ to ‘Student*’.

An example where this might be useful is: I have a Person class, and depends on where this person will do in life, I will transform it into Student, Teacher, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, you are assigning parent pointer to child pointer.

Comment: Read about *virtual functions*. That's the canonical way to solve this problem.

Comment: @john: virtual or not, a Person is not a Student. So it will be wrong anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Person *p = s;
```

works because every `Student` is also a `Person`.

```
Student *s = p;
```

doesn't work because a `Person` is not necessarily a `Student`.

Comment: Can't use dynamic_cast with the code as posted, since the base class does not contain any virtual functions.

Comment: @john Thanks for the reply, really help me a lot. So why only with virtual functions, I can use dynamic_cast?

Comment: @AnhTran If a class has one or more virtual fucntion then something called a *vtable* will be added by the compiler to the class. This makes the class a little bit bigger than it would be otherwise (typically it makes the class bigger by the size of a pointer). A vtable is also needed to implement dynamic_cast, so the C++ rules say that you must already have at least one virtual function for dynamic_cast to work.